# Cucumber-rails - Remove gem and all dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is it possible to remove a gem and automatically all their dependencies?

If it is possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To remove gem from the app with all it's dependencies 
remove gem from `Gemfile` and run

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I removed the cucumber-rails from the gemfile, but the dependencies as cucumber still at the list when run bundle show / gem list. =/

Comment: Maybe some other gem has `Cucumber` as a dependency.

Comment: But the cucumber-rails still there too.

The gem is already installed.

I need to remove using gem uninstall cucumber-rails, remove form gemfile and run bundle install?

Comment: Show your gemfile in the question if you are still having trouble.